# Sql Editor plugin missng from eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I have eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1). i want to install a sql editor plugin to open (.sql) files. But while installing new software it ask for a link or a plugin in your local. Searched on google but didn't get any plugin.
Can anybody help me in this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link - http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/

You can install and update Eclipse SQL Explorer via the eclipse update mechanism. The update site for Eclipse SQL Explorer is http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/